# Exception executing batch. Spring application

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jakarta-ee

I have such service:

```
@Service
public class UserEventServiceImpl implements UserEventService {
@Autowired
UserEventDao userEventDao;

@Override
public UserEvent getOrCreateUserEvent(String guid) {
    return userEventDao.getOrCreateUserEvent(guid);
}

@Override
public void updateUserEvent(UserEvent userEvent) {
    userEventDao.update(userEvent);
}

@Override
public void processEventType(String guid, EventType type) {
    UserEvent userEvent = getOrCreateUserEvent(guid);
    switch (type) {
        case DOWNLOAD_STARTED: {
            userEvent.setDownloadInstallStarted(new Date());
            updateUserEvent(userEvent);
            break;
        }
        case DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE: {
            userEvent.setDownloadInstallCompleted(new Date());
            updateUserEvent(userEvent);
            break;
        }
        case UPDATE_DOWNLOAD_STARTED: {
            userEvent.setDownloadUpdateStarted(new Date());
            updateUserEvent(userEvent);
            break;
        }
        case UPDATE_DOWNLOAD_FINISHED: {
            userEvent.setDownloadUpdateCompleted(new Date());
            updateUserEvent(userEvent);
            break;
        }
        case UPDATE_COMPLETE: {
            userEvent.setUpdateCompleted(true);
            updateUserEvent(userEvent);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

}

And such dao class:

```
@Repository
public class UserEventDaoHb extends BaseDaoHb<UserEvent> implements UserEventDao {

public UserEventDaoHb() {
    super(UserEvent.class);
}

@Override
public UserEvent getOrCreateUserEvent(String guid) {
    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    Date date = new Date();
    try {
        date = formatter.parse(formatter.format(date));
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        //do nothing. Impossible to happen
    }
    UserEvent event = findOneByParams(Restrictions.eq("guid", guid), Restrictions.eq("date", date));
    if (event == null) {
        event = new UserEvent();
        event.setGuid(guid);
        event.setDate(date);
        getHibernateTemplate().save(event);
        getHibernateTemplate().flush();

    }
    return event;
}
```

}

UserEvent is a simple POJO object. 
This code works perfectly at local and test server but when i run it at production it causes such exception:

> ERROR [http-apr-8080-exec-55] - 2014-06-20 07:27:14 - (BatchingBatcher.java:73) - Exception executing batch: 
>   org.hibernate.StaleStateException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1

As i understand, it happen because UserEvent does not exists yet in DB when its update should be.
Have any ideas how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I forget to add *@Transactional* annotation to *getOrCreateUserEvent()* method.